# ListBox not updating after deserialization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, serialization, listbox

I am trying to make a display of my items listed on the right side of my window. When I first initialize my window, everything works perfectly. What I do is, I deserialize a file and get my `ObservableCollection<Model.Resources>`. All the items from my list are shown in the ListBox. 
When I enter my Add Resource window, and add some more resources, I serialize those objects into a file. When I am finished with adding, I call a method called `refresh()` that deserializes some files and updates my `ObservableCollection<Model.Resources>`. When I am finished with that, ListBox doesn't update until I restart my program.

XAML of my Window that has ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="itemList" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="7,23,6,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#324251" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=resources}" FontSize="16" Foreground="Wheat"/>
```

Relevant code of my Window class:

```
public partial class GlowingEarth : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Model.Etiquette> _tags;
    private ObservableCollection<Model.Resource> _resources;
    private ObservableCollection<Model.Type> _types;
    public ObservableCollection<Model.Etiquette> tags
    {
        get
        {
            return _tags;
        }
        set
        {
            _tags = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("tags");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Model.Resource> resources
    {
        get
        {
            return _resources;
        }
        set
        {
            _resources = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("resources");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Model.Type> types
    {
        get
        {
            return _types;
        }
        set
        {
            _types = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("types");
        }
    }

    private BinaryFormatter fm;
    private FileStream sm = null;
    private string path;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public GlowingEarth()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tags = new ObservableCollection<Model.Etiquette>();
        resources = new ObservableCollection<Model.Resource>();
        types = new ObservableCollection<Model.Type>();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        refresh();
    }

public void refresh()
    {
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "typeList");
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            fm = new BinaryFormatter();
            sm = File.OpenRead(path);
            _types = (ObservableCollection<Model.Type>)fm.Deserialize(sm);
            sm.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "tagList");
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            fm = new BinaryFormatter();
            sm = File.OpenRead(path);
            _tags = (ObservableCollection<Model.Etiquette>)fm.Deserialize(sm);
            sm.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "reslist");
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            fm = new BinaryFormatter();
            sm = File.OpenRead(path);
            _resources = (ObservableCollection<Model.Resource>)fm.Deserialize(sm);
            sm.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Can you please tell me, what on earth is going on, and why isn't my list updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `refresh()` method you change the value of a *field*

```
_resources = (ObservableCollection<Model.Resource>)fm.Deserialize(sm);
```

it does not call `OnPropertyChanged("resources");`

you should use `resources` *property*

```
resources = (ObservableCollection<Model.Resource>)fm.Deserialize(sm);
```

same for `_types` and `_tags`